# How do we treat a י"א in the Shulchan Aruch?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, shulchan-aruch, machlokes

Is there a general principle for how we treat a י"א = יש אומרים (*yesh omrim*, "some say") cited in the Shulchan Aruch for the purposes of determining halacha? If not, are there examples of two halachos where we use different approaches towards a י"א (e.g. following one but not the other, treating one as going *l'chumra* and one as going *l'kula*, etc.)?

Comment: in the sefer yad malachi he puts down the rules

Comment: Remember the general rule for general rules: beware exceptions thereof.

Comment: @rabbi Do you know the location of this in the sefer?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=27&format=text

Comment: Chayei Adam https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=24600&st=&pgnum=2 says when it's י״א וי״א he rules strictly for biblical questions and leniently for rabbinic questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Synopsized from *Yad Malachi* (*K'lalei Haposkim* - *HSh"' VRM"'* [#13,14,16,17](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14122&st=&pgnum=415)):

- When the Shulchan Aruch quotes an unattributed *halacha* followed by one introduced with the words "*yesh om'rim*" it indicates that the unattributed opinion is authoritative.

  - This is [almost] universally agreed despite the fact that occasionally the conclusion of *Beis Yosef* coincides with an opinion under the heading "*yesh om'rim*" and not with the unattributed one that preceded it.
- When it says "*yesh om'rim* X *v'yesh om'rim* Y" it is deciding in favor of the second opinion.

  - Some interpret such a formulation as *non*-determinative.
- When it introduces an opinion with "*yesh om'rim*" and follows that with an opinion beginning "*v'yesh mi she'omer*" the first one is authoritative.

  - Some disagree and therefore this rule is unreliable.

Comment: [almost] universally ... I love it :P

Comment: Where does he get these rules from? Did Rav Karo ever clarify? Did people just make it up?

Comment: @DoubleAA Yad Malachi gets them from all kinds of other _sifrei k'lalim_ and interspersed in standard commentaries. He cites them on those pages. If you're asking how Rav Yosef Karo ranked opinions, there are some indications therein as well. In some instances it's actually obvious since his explicitly stated algorithm (in the intro to _Beis Yosef_) is majority-of-small-sample-based.